# How to set already instantiated ViewController to View

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs5

I'm trying to use MVVM with multiple views, but I cannot set the same ViewController instance to several views. If I set controller using `controller : 'main'`, I would get a new instance of the viewcontroller. Is there any trick to bind the view to the same viewcontroller as the first View or Caller View?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to use a view controller with multiple views - they are explicitly intended to be bound to a single instance of the view.

You can use regular controllers to co-ordinate multiple views, though.